# Python: expressions with variables represented as list of tuples, combining like terms: Logic issue

Tags: python

Logic is flawed in some way. This is my First question asked on SO. Anyways, Here:

So a list is passed into the function, the list represents an un-simplified expression like
`2x-5y-3x+7y+3z+6z = [(2,'x'),(-5,'y'),(-3,x),(7,'y'),(3,'z'),(6,'z')]`,
 and I must combine the like terms and return a list with the simplified expression, which would be `[(-1,'x),(4,'y'),(9,'z')]` in this instance.

Traceback error states that my iterator which I am using as an index is out of bounds, Not sure how since I am only stepping once starting from `0`, up to the `length of the list-1`.

```
def groupLikeTerms(exp):
   newlist=[]
   sumVar=0
   for x in range(0,len(exp)-1,1):
      Letter=exp[x][1]
      if Letter in newlist:
        continue
      else:
        for x2 in range(0,len(exp)-1,1):
          if exp[x2][1]==Letter:
            sumVar+=exp[x2][0]
        newlist.append([(sumVar,Letter)])
  exp=newlist[:]
  return exp
```

Comment: `range(start_index, stop, step)` goes **up to but not including** `stop`.  In other words, *generally* you'll want to use the `range(0, len(mylist), 1)` pattern. (or simply `range(len(mylist))`).  This will automatically stop your loop at `length of the list-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [(2,'x'),(-5,'y'),(-3,'x')]
final_data = [(a, sum(i[0] for i in list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
```

Output:

```
[('x', -1), ('y', -5)]
```

Edit: using data from your most recent edit:

```
s = [(2,'x'),(-5,'y'),(-3,'x'),(7,'y'),(3,'z'),(6,'z')] 
final_data = [(a, sum(i[0] for i in list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
```

Output:

```
[('x', -1), ('y', 2), ('z', 9)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way of doing using `collections.defaultdict(int)`

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [(2,'x'),(-5,'y'),(-3,'x')] 
d_dict = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in l:
    d_dict[v]+=k

[(v,k) for k,v in d_dict.items()]
#Output:
#[(-1, 'x'), (-5, 'y')]
```